# Rails 3.2, RSpec, Factory Girl : NameError: uninitialized constant Factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

Ive been following [this](http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html) introductory to Rails testing and Ive run into an issue I cant seem to find the solution to. Im very familiar with Rails but this is my first foray into testing.

Anyhow, I have a very basic model test, not even fully implemented and when I try and run `rspec spec/models/admin_spec.rb`. I get the following error in the `Admin has a valid factory` line (full code below)

```
Admin has a valid factory
 Failure/Error: Factory.create(:admin).should be_valid
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Factory
 # ./spec/models/admin_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I assume FactoryGirl isnt being loaded for some reason but I was under the impression it should be automatically loaded. Below is the full code from my Gemfile, /spec/models/admin_spec.rb and /spec/factories/admins.rb

Thanks very much for your help

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'json'
gem "paperclip", '~>3.0'
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'nested_form', :git => 'https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
# gem 'compass'

group :development do
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'wirble'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

**/spec/factories/admin.rb**

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin do |f|
    f.name Faker::Name.name
    f.email Faker::Internet.email
  end
end
```

**/spec/models/admin_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    Factory.create(:admin).should be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a name"
  it "is invalid without an email"
end
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It should be `FactoryGirl.create` instead. Apparently `Factory` was deprecated and now has been removed, look at the comments in the link you provided :)

Comment: ahhh *sigh*. Haha, thanks very much. I did a find on the page for the "uninitialized constant Factory error" but didn't read close enough. I got the feeling it'd be something simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

In fact in your `spec_helper.rb` under `Rspec.configure do...end` you can add

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

This will save you the trouble of the prefixing `FactoryGirl.`  before `:build` and `:create` altogether:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Admin do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    create(:admin).should be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a name"
  it "is invalid without an email"
end
```

Refer: [FactoryGirl Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

Answer (score 9):

This isn't an answer to your question, but I noticed there is an obscure error in your use of Faker with FactoryGirl. *f.name* and *f.email* will be the same for every FactoryGirl.create or FactoryGirl.build.

```
f.name Faker::Name.name
f.email Faker::Internet.email
```

Add curly braces around the Faker calls so that each reference to a Factory will generate random Faker data.

```
f.name { Faker::Name.name }
f.email { Faker::Internet.email }
```

Comment: Ah yup, I did catch that one later on, while I was reviewing my code, but thanks for the heads up anyhow.

Comment: Thank you for this! Stupid mistake but easy to miss

Answer (score 1):

Also, be sure that you are including the require statement in your spec_helper.rb file.

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```