# Rails: Troubleshooting Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

I'm trying to do unit tests on a fairly complex model. Unfortunately, I can't get them off the ground because Factory Girl is failing to create valid factories. I get this error message in my console:

```
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5←[0m ←[36m# User has a valid factory←[0m
```

But that's it. The factory is 22 lines:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.name { Faker::Name.name }
    f.username { Faker::Internet.user_name }
    f.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    f.password { Faker::Lorem.characters(char_count = rand(6..20)) }
    f.password_confirmation { "#{password}" }
    f.time_zone { Faker::Address.time_zone }
    f.location_name { Faker::Address.city }
    f.latitude { Faker::Address.latitude }
    f.longitude { Faker::Address.longitude }
    f.slug { "#{username}" }
    f.hide_location { [true, false].sample }
    f.ignore_bookclub_requests { [true, false].sample }
    f.group_distance { rand * 100 }
    f.remote_groups { [true, false].sample }
    f.whuffie { rand * 100 }

  end
end
```

But I have no idea which line the problem is stemming from. Although a more experienced programmer can probably point it, I'm more curious about how I can troubleshoot this and future problems on my own. How can I find out where the problem is coming from? Typically Rails is good about pointing to a specific line or block of code. Is there a way I can prompt it to do so here?

Comment: One thing I noticed quickly is when you're setting the password, I think it should just be `Faker::Lorem.characters(rand(6..20))`, without the `char_count = `. That might be screwing up something, but not necessarily in regards to your exact error. For a longer stack trace, try wrapping the offending line in a `begin..rescue` block, and then output `e.message` for the error message, and `e.backtrace`. Sometimes there is more in there than what you'll get in your console.

Comment: Could you post your user model?

Comment: do you have another factory called the same thing?

Comment: @MrDanA I haven't used begin/rescue before, and I'm a little unclear about how to implement it. Do you mean to wrap the contents of the factory in begin, then to have e.message in the rescue block? I gave that a shot, but I'm not getting any more info in my console. Is there somewhere else where it might show up?

Comment: Looks like the problem was in my user_spec.rb file. I had used Factory.create(:user), which according to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875634/rails-3-2-rspec-factory-girl-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-factory) is depreciated. It now has to be FactoryGirl.create(:user).